# what is wrong with my span

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, html

hi I am trying to have a thumbnail at the button of my picture, but it goes out of the whole span that I have here is my code here is the whole code http://jsfiddle.net/dP4eL/
I am using twitter bootstrap

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home"><div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="thumbnails">
                <li class="span4">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="Hydrangeas.jpg" alt="product 1">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h5>Product detail</h5>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore       magna aliqua.</p>
                        <br>
                        <div class="span1">
                            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="Hydrangeas.jpg" alt="image">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">fav</a>
                            </div>
                        </br>
                    </div>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Thank you

Comment: Two questions: what should `</br>` close and what's that lonely `</p>` hanging between two `div`s?

Comment: and you have about 4 divs that are not closed.

Comment: I thought this <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore       magna aliqua.</p> <br> would take me to next line, so I can have a thumbnail of the picture under the description inside <ul class="thumbnails">

Comment: @behzad_b That is not what was asked.

Comment: The code continues with other spans under the divs that are not close yet

Comment: here is the whole code http://jsfiddle.net/dP4eL/

Comment: @Daedalus that is what i want the thumbnail to show at the bottom as span1

Comment: A few heads ups: There is only one type of line-break tag, and that is a `<br />`.  No opening, no closing.  Just singular.  Also, div tags cannot go inside paragraph tags.  Only in-line elements may; no block-level elements(div is block level).

Comment: @Daedalus thanx for the heads up, I did that but still the thumbnail of the picture at the bottom goes outside of the first div

Comment: @behzad_b Please update your code here with what you currently have.

Comment: @Daedalus http://jsfiddle.net/dP4eL/2/ here it is, if you look at the left panel in the results under the product you see how fav is out of place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is kinda hard to understand - i guess you do want that little "image / Favbutton"-Box to remain in its parent-div?!

Bootstrap should use the floats in the right way so, try to **add** to your .thumbnail-class:

```
.thumbnail { overflow: hidden; }
```

If that´s what you want to achieve.

Comment: NO i want to, i want that little imag/fav button to stay inside the parent

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the limited code you have there, but if you would like a div to cut off extra content you can set a width and height for it and set it's overflow to hidden like so:

```
.span1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Just change the width and height to your specifications.

Comment: i change still it goes out of order... if you see it in the jsfiddle the first one is out of order

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the class `span` has the property `float: left`.  Float removes the element from the float of the document.

```css
[class*="span"] {
    float: left;
}
```

You have multiple instances of this css in your .. css declarations.  The way I see it, you have two options.

Either delete `float: left` from all instances, or apply a [clearfix css class to your elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-actually-is-clearfix).  This will ensure your div remains in the flow of your document, and your parent div expands to contain it.

I would create a demo for you, but there is so much css in your js fiddle that js fiddle cannot parse it at a reasonable speed.

Answer (score 0):

remove your float:left setting for your span. If you aren't happy about that then try using table :D